# Жрет оперативную память, в чем причина?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, память, виртуальная-память

Пишу сервис на питоне по классификации изображений. Взял для формирования чекпоинта .ckpt этот скрипт https://github.com/bansalshubh91/Image-Similarity-using-Deep-Ranking/blob/master/Train.py , но он использует уже готовую модель, а не создает ее заново, поэтому я закоментил загрузку модели и добавил метод мейн для запуска метода train_p. Но... после запуска мейна -  начинает жрать оперативу, программа зависает, не работает. Подскажите в чем ошибка? Специально уменьшил дата сет до 200 фотографий, проблема не решилась

```
def find_classes(dir):
    classes = [d for d in os.listdir(dir)]
    classes.sort()
    class_to_idx = {classes[i]: i for i in range(len(classes))}
    return classes, class_to_idx


def make_dataset(dir, class_to_idx):
    images = []
    dir = os.path.expanduser(dir)
    for target in sorted(os.listdir(dir)):
        d = os.path.join(dir, target, 'images')
        if not os.path.isdir(d):
            continue
        for root, _, fnames in sorted(os.walk(d)):
            for fname in sorted(fnames):
                path = os.path.join(root, fname)
                item = (path, target)
                images.append(item)
    return images


def make_test_dataset(dir):
    images = []
    dir = os.path.expanduser(dir)
    d = os.path.join(dir, 'images')
    r = np.array([x.split('\t') for x in open(os.path.join(dir, 'val_annotations.txt')).readlines()])
    for i in range(len(r)):
        path = os.path.join(d, r[i][0])
        item = (path, r[i][1])
        images.append(item)
    return images


def pil_loader(path):
    # open path as file to avoid ResourceWarning (https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/835)
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        img = Image.open(f)
        return img.convert('RGB')


class DatasetFolder(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, loader=pil_loader, transform=None, train=True, test=None, sample=None):
        if test is not None:
            samples = make_test_dataset(root)
        else:
            classes, class_to_idx = find_classes(root)
            samples = make_dataset(root, class_to_idx)
            self.classes = classes
            self.class_to_idx = class_to_idx
        self.root = root
        self.loader = loader
        self.samples = samples
        self.transform = transform
        self.train = train
        self.sample = sample

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        path, target = self.samples[index]
        query_image = self.loader(path)
        if self.transform is not None:
            query_image = self.transform(query_image)
        if self.train is not True and self.sample is None:
            return query_image, target, path
        if self.train is not True and self.sample is not None:
            negative1 = random.randint(0, 9999)
            path_neg1, target_neg1 = self.samples[negative1]
            while target_neg1 == target:
                negative1 = random.randint(0, 9999)
                path_neg1, target_neg1 = self.samples[negative1]
            negative2 = random.randint(0, 9999)
            path_neg2, target_neg2 = self.samples[negative2]
            while target_neg2 in [target, target_neg1]:
                negative2 = random.randint(0, 9999)
                path_neg2, target_neg2 = self.samples[negative2]
            negative3 = random.randint(0, 9999)
            path_neg3, target_neg3 = self.samples[negative3]
            while target_neg3 in [target, target_neg1, target_neg2]:
                negative3 = random.randint(0, 9999)
                path_neg3, target_neg3 = self.samples[negative3]
            negative4 = random.randint(0, 9999)
            path_neg4, target_neg4 = self.samples[negative4]
            while target_neg4 in [target, target_neg1, target_neg2, target_neg3]:
                negative4 = random.randint(0, 9999)
                path_neg4, target_neg4 = self.samples[negative4]
            negative_image1 = self.loader(path_neg1)
            negative_image2 = self.loader(path_neg2)
            negative_image3 = self.loader(path_neg3)
            negative_image4 = self.loader(path_neg4)
            if self.transform is not None:
                negative_image1 = self.transform(negative_image1)
                negative_image2 = self.transform(negative_image2)
                negative_image3 = self.transform(negative_image3)
                negative_image4 = self.transform(negative_image4)
            return query_image, target, path, negative_image1, target_neg1, path_neg1, negative_image2, target_neg2, path_neg2, negative_image3, target_neg3, path_neg3, negative_image4, target_neg4, path_neg4
        positive = random.randint(0, 99999)
        path_pos, target_pos = self.samples[positive]
        while target_pos != target or positive == index:
            positive = random.randint(0, 99999)
            path_pos, target_pos = self.samples[positive]
        negative = random.randint(0, 99999)
        path_neg, target_neg = self.samples[negative]
        while target_neg == target:
            negative = random.randint(0, 99999)
            path_neg, target_neg = self.samples[negative]
        positive_image = self.loader(path_pos)
        negative_image = self.loader(path_neg)
        if self.transform is not None:
            positive_image = self.transform(positive_image)
            negative_image = self.transform(negative_image)
        return query_image, positive_image, negative_image

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.samples)


def train_p():
    # Download and construct CIFAR-10 dataset.
    train_dataset = DatasetFolder(root='./tiny-imagenet-200/train',
                                  transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256), transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                                                transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                                                transforms.ToTensor()]), train=True)
    batch_size = 8
    # Data loader (this provides queues and threads in a very simple way).
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                               batch_size=batch_size,
                                               shuffle=True, num_workers=32)

    # # #Model architecture
    model_urls['resnet50'] = model_urls['resnet50'].replace('https://', 'http://')
    model = models.resnet50(pretrained=False)
    num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
    model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 4096)
    # model.load_state_dict(torch.load('params.ckpt'))
    model.cuda()
    # # #Stochastic gradient descent optimizer
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    num_epochs = 15
    model.train()
    train_loss = []
    triplet_loss = nn.TripletMarginLoss(margin=1.0)
    # Train Model
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for query_images, positive_images, negative_images in train_loader:
            Q, P, N = Variable(query_images).cuda(), Variable(positive_images).cuda(), Variable(negative_images).cuda()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            Q_output = model(Q)
            P_output = model(P)
            N_output = model(N)
            loss = triplet_loss(Q_output, P_output, N_output)
            loss.backward()
            train_loss.append(loss.data[0])
            optimizer.step()
        loss_epoch = np.mean(train_loss)
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'params.ckpt')
        torch.save(model, 'model.ckpt')
        print(epoch, loss_epoch)
    return 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_p()
```

Cначала жрет оперативу, потом через какое - то время начинает жрать cpu:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использовать готовую модель - это значит прочитать/загрузить все параметры и веса __заранее обученной__ нейронной сети и использовать ее для предсказаний. Процесс обучения - самый ресурсоемкий.

Comment: @MaxU это понятно... но я уменьшил число фотографий до 200. это уже и так очень мало....

Comment: Все известные мне модули пытаются минимизировать время обучения. Соответственно будет использоваться максимум ресурсов. Обычно на практике используют уже обученные модели...

Comment: @MaxU я не против взять готовые модели. только где их скачать. весь интернет перерыл

Comment: это зависит от того что конкретно (какие изображения) вы хотите классифицировать...

Comment: @MaxU обучить хочу абсолютно любой имейдж нет

Comment: например в [Keras](https://keras.io/applications/) полно обученных моделей...

Comment: @MaxU не пойдет... я совсем забыл. у меня совокупность нейросетей. то есть нужно самому обучать(((